# Lampp PHP doesn't work like environment in PHP

Tags: php, linux, xampp, version, lampp

I'm using LAMPP (XAMPP on Linux) to operate my server.

LAMPP has its own php binaries `/opt/lampp/bin/php`, which is different from the php version I have in `/usr/bin/php`. That is, when I've installed extensions using the command line, they've been successfully added to the original `/usr/bin/php`, but the php version which is associated with Lampp didn't recognized these extensions.

The question is, how to get these extensions into work with Lampp?

I can change my original php to the one in Lampp (so I can normally install extensions) or I can change the PHP associated with Lampp to be the original one but I don't know the way to do this.

Comment: Change the entries in the php.ini associated with LAMP?

Comment: Can you be more specific please? @junkfoodjunkie

Comment: Why do you use something like `xampp` on a perfectly fine Linux system?

Comment: I've migrated from windows to linux, so I wanted a similar environment.
Do you think I can run Magento 2 without LAMPP? @arkascha

Comment: And, just by the way, `LAMPP` does _not_ stand for "xampp on linux", but for "Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP, Perl" which is what is easily installed on any Linux system with just a few clicks in the software management. No need at all for `xampp`.

Comment: Well, since you have two installations, you will end up with duplicate files, misleading configs, and so on. I would recommend getting rid of the extra bloat, and just install PHP, MySQL and your preferred webserver (I assume Apache) on the box, without any other "wrapper". It is very simple, and you will find detailed info about installing it on almost every single distro out there via a quick Google search.

Comment: Thanks guys, I've done exactly as what you've told me, and it's now recognizing the environment PHP. This is great!